# Unable to read data from TCP/IP open port in Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, socket.io

Hi I am newbie into `Socket` programming, Below is the code I have tried connecting with TCP/IP port and able to connect successfully.

Once after the connection I am sending a message to PORT and it is received by PORT.

Now, I have problem in reading data from PORT

**SampleCode**

```
 Thread clientThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                socket = new Socket(ipNumber, portNumber);
                Log.d("debug","@@socket=="+socket);
                // attach to socket's output stream with auto flush turned on
                // Send message to the server
                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
                Log.d("debug","the message is"+out.toString());
                out.println(message);

                // Receive data from port and update in Ui
                InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                byte result[] = readBytes(inputStream);
                String s = new String(result);
                Log.d("debug","the string result is="+s);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                final String message = e.getMessage();
                Log.d("debug","the error message is"+message);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(!((Activity) MainActivity.this).isFinishing()){
                            if (message.startsWith("failed to connect")){
                                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                        .setCancelable(false)
                                        .setTitle(getString(R.string.dialog_alert))
                                        .setMessage(getString(R.string.unable_to_connect_port))
                                        .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.dialog_ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                                dialog.dismiss();

                                            }
                                        }).show();

                            }
                            else if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("Connection reset")){
                                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                        .setCancelable(false)
                                        .setTitle(getString(R.string.dialog_alert))
                                        .setMessage(getString(R.string.connection_closed))
                                        .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.dialog_ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                dialog.dismiss();
                                            }
                                        }).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    clientThread.start();


public byte[] readBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        // this dynamically extends to take the bytes you read
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // this is storage overwritten on each iteration with bytes
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // we need to know how may bytes were read to write them to the byteBuffer
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        // and then we can return your byte array.
        return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
    }
```

Please help me to out how do I read data from an Open TCP/IP Port. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well what is the problem now?

Comment: `Log.d("debug","the message is"+out.toString());` ??? What do you see in the logcat? Dont you mean: `Log.d("debug","the message is: "+ message);`?

Comment: It prints nothing..

Comment: My problem is to read data from an Open TCP/IP extenal port

Comment: What do you mean with `it` ? And 'nothing' ? It should at least print 'the message is: '. And if that is all then 'message' woul be empty. Why are you sending an empty message?

Comment: Yes, it prints only this "the message is". after this it prints nothing i mean to say..

Comment: if the connection is closed from TCP/IP port then immediately i get response here `Log.d("debug","the string result is="+s);`
But, i need to read data when PORT is always open.. how should achieve this? please help me

Comment: Why are you sending an empty message? And hence an empty line?

Comment: Tell what the server received. And tell what the server is sending in reply.

Comment: Not sending empty message, I have globally intialized the message as `String message = "Initial Message";`
Server will recieve the same message as `Initial Message`
And then server will send me back the `JSON` Data